# Set default value on a radio input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, input

In my form on rails I have a type of radio input and if the users choose "Yes" or "No" the corresponding input text changes its attributes. Basically if the user selects "Yes" he will have an Input where he will have to enter a value but if he selects "No" he will not be able to change the value not default. Until everything works except that if users select "Yes" and enter a value but realize that they have made a mistake and want to select "No" the value is not reset by default and it is the one that he entered in the "Yes" that remains. Why ???
Here's what I did:

```
    <%= f.label :post_author_yes, 'Yes' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :author, 'Yes', class: 'radio-inline', onclick:'javascript:yesnoCheck();' %>
    <%= f.label :post_author_no, 'No' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :author, 'No', class: 'radio-inline', onclick:'javascript:yesnoCheck();' %>
    <div id="input" style="display:none">
       <%= f.text_field :author, class: 'edit_input', placeholder: 'Real Author', :readonly => true %>
     </div>
```

```
  function yesnoCheck(){
      if(document.getElementById('post_author_yes').checked)
      {
        document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('post_author').readOnly = false;
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('post_author').readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById("post_author").setAttribute('value', 'No');
      }
  }
```

Comment: It is because you only hide the field, but not reset the field. JavaScript does not know that when you hide a field that you want to empty it.

Comment: Ok so how to reset it ?

Answer (score 0):

To reset a field to its initial state, you have to set the `value` property of the `input` element to an empty string (`''`).

Look at the example below where the line `postAuthor.value = '';` resets the `post_author` by changing the `value` property.

```js
const author = document.getElementById('author');
const postAuthor = document.getElementById('post_author');
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="post-author"]');

radios.forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if (event.target.value === 'Yes') {
      author.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      author.classList.add('hidden');
      postAuthor.value = '';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Post Author Yes
  <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="post-author" value="Yes">
</label>

<label>Post Author No
  <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="post-author" value="No">
</label>

<div id="author" class="hidden">
  <label for="post_author">Real Author</label>
  <input id="post_author" class="edit_input" type="text" placeholder="Real Author">
</div>
```